# What replaces ObjectId.massageToObjectId() in new mongo java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, objectid

According to the documentation of API of new MongoDB Java driver 2.12 [which can be seen here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#massageToObjectId(java.lang.Object))  the method that converts string into an ObjectId is deprecated and will be dropped in 3.x drivers.

What are we supposed to rewrite the code to use? The documentation does not state this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe just the [constructor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#ObjectId(java.lang.String)) if you want to convert a String

```
new ObjectId(String)
```

Comment: Looks like this constructor was present from 2.0. Why would anyone need massageToObjectId, when a constructor can do it?

Comment: The documentation reads `Deprecated. This method is NOT a part of public API and...` so my guess would be it was never intended for anyone but the driver to massage things to ObjectId in this way. I don't know what it is used for internaly by the driver.

Comment: Too bad they exported it to public API by making the method public, when they did not want it to be a part of the public API. Now our project needs to be refactored. A lot. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Ev0oD sorry to hear that it will bite you when you migrate in the future - but it's great that you are being proactive on the deprecation warnings now.  As its a small helper you can always bring it in house and refactor to use your utility helper. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/r2.12.3/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java#L116-L130

Comment: Thanks, I might as well use this. My first thought was to try to replace "ObjectId.massageToObjectId(" with "new ObjectId(" everywhere. I'll try and see which will be easier to accomplish.